# what mean about the char of <: at the typescript?

Tags: typescript

Question:

- What is the meaning of the char at <:?
- Where can I find the documentation about it?
- How do I understand it?

[Link](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md#literal).

```
                   this char mean
interface Literal <: Expression {
   type: "Literal";
   value: string | boolean | null | number | RegExp;
}
```

Comment: *If S is a subtype of T, the subtyping relation is often written S <: T, to mean that any term of type S can be safely used in a context where a term of type T is expected.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping

Answer (score 1):

This is not TypeScript. It looks to mean "is a subtype of".

For example, `interface Literal <: Expression` means that a `Literal` is a type of [`Expression`](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md#expressions). Similarly, `interface Expression <: Node` means that an `Expression` is a type of `Node`. (In the abstract syntax tree, every element in the tree is some type of Node)

When there are multiple identifiers on the right, eg:

```
interface FunctionExpression <: Function, Expression
```

that indicates that the left is a type of both (eg a `FunctionExpression` counts as both a `Function` node and as an `Expression` node)